# How to prevent git push when there are eslint errors?Husky, lint-staged, eslint

Tags: javascript, eslint, husky, lint-staged

Hi StackOverflow community,

I'm having trouble preventing a git push when there are eslint errors in my code. I'm using eslint with husky and lint-staged to catch linting errors before they are committed to the repository. However, when there are errors and I try to push my changes, they still get pushed.

So currently we have linting configured using lint-staged package which doesn't work and added additional linting call. Could we fix linting in lint-staged instead so developers can notice lint errors on staged files?

Here's my .lintstagedrc file:

```
{
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
    "prettier --write"
  ],
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": [
    "npm run lint"
  ]
}
```

package.json:

```
`"dependencies": {
    "@auth0/auth0-react": "^1.9.0",
    "@dezeroku/serverless-certificate-creator": "^1.6.0",
    "@emoji-mart/data": "^1.0.2",
    "@floating-ui/react-dom-interactions": "^0.9.2",
    "@sentry/react": "^7.30.0",
    "camelcase-keys": "^7.0.2",
    "classnames": "^2.3.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.2",
    "emoji-mart": "^5.2.1",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.6",
    "linkify-react": "^3.0.4",
    "linkifyjs": "^3.0.5",
    "msw": "^0.40.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-hook-form": "7.43.1",
    "react-query": "^3.34.19",
    "react-router-dom": "6.6.1",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-sortablejs": "6.1.4",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "react-timeago": "^6.2.1",
    "react-toastify": "9.1.2",
    "react-transition-group": "4.4.5",
    "react-truncate": "2.4.0",
    "react-truncate-markup": "5.1.2",
    "recharts": "2.1.14",
    "serverless-finch": "^4.0.0",
    "snakecase-keys": "^5.1.2",
    "sortablejs": "1.15.0",
    "use-react-router-breadcrumbs": "^3.1.0",
    "uuid": "9.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/builder-webpack5": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/manager-webpack5": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/node-logger": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/preset-create-react-app": "^4.1.2",
    "@storybook/react": "6.5.10",
    "@storybook/testing-library": "^0.0.13",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.2",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.4",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@trivago/prettier-plugin-sort-imports": "^4.1.1",
    "airbnb-prop-types": "^2.16.0",
    "babel-plugin-named-exports-order": "^0.0.2",
    "chromatic": "^6.7.4",
    "cypress": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.3.8",
    "mockdate": "^3.0.5",
    "prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "webpack": "^5.76.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "test": "TZ=UTC react-scripts test",
    "test:prepush": "npm run test -- --watchAll=false",
    "test:ci": "CI=true npm run test -- --coverage",
    "lint": "eslint src --max-warnings=0",
    "lint-staged": "lint-staged",
    "format": "prettier --write \"./**/*.{js,jsx}\"",
    "eslint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -p 6006 -s public",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook -s public",
    "chromatic": "npx chromatic --project-token=bf77f85e9cc4"
  },
```

husky/.pre-push

```
 #!/bin/sh
. "$(dirname "$0")/_/husky.sh"

npm run lint-staged && npm run test:prepush
```

.eslintrc

```
 {
  "extends": ["react-app", "react-app/jest"],
  "ignorePatterns": ["**/*.spec.jsx", "**/vendor/*.js"],
  "rules": {
    "no-duplicate-imports": "error",
    "react/prop-types": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

We have setup `husky` + `lint-staged` to run all linters on commit: prettier, eslint, stylelint, spotless, etc.

Here is an example:

```
// lint-staged.config.js
module.exports = {
  '*.{js,html,json,md,xml,yaml,yml}': 'node node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js --write',
  '*.ts': ['./eslint-helper.sh', 'node node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js --write'],
  '*.{css,scss}': [
    'node frontend/node_modules/stylelint/bin/stylelint.js --ignore-path frontend/.stylelintignore --cache --cache-location frontend/.stylelintcache --fix',
    'node node_modules/prettier/bin-prettier.js --write',
  ],
  '*.{java,kt}': (filePaths) => {
    const filenames = filePaths.map((filePath) => filePath.split('/').pop());
    return `mvn spotless:apply -DspotlessFiles=.*${filenames.join(',.*')}`;
  },
};
```

- eslint-helper.sh: we did this due to having a monorepo, maybe you can avoid it

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
cd frontend
node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js --config .eslintrc.json --fix "$@"
```

## Extra Info

In regards to your current configuration. The code below is incorrect because you have the same file extension defined in multiple entries, .i.e. `js,jsx,ts,tsx,json`. They must be unique because each of those commands are being executed in parallel. This means that you will end up with race conditions, lint-staged will execute the commands in parallel and the last one to finish will overwrite what another command did, i.e. prettier could overwrite lint or the other way around.

```
// incorrect config
{
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,css,scss,md}": [
    "prettier --write"
  ],
  "src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json}": [
    "npm run lint"
  ]
}
```